# New cable modem giving Android Phone time outs on sites

Tags: networking, wi-fi

I just changed from DSL to Cable Broadband and I'm having a rather peculiar problem. Most of the time I get time outs from hosts using my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone while my other wireless devices work fine (Win Laptop, Ipod). My phone works well on WiFi at work, but it's not getting along with my Arris (Model: TG862A) Cable modem. I haven't updated the phone's firmware (5.0.1) or anything. I can ping sites and other devices in my network, but a lot of times can't access websites. I have even thought if it was the DNS server and I have changed to Google's DNS Servers and entered the server's IP address, but nothing. I get brief moments where everything works fine and then it's gone.

Just wanted to know if anyone has had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since other devices are working fine, and your phone works okay on other networks, it's likely a specific compatibility issue between your phone and your home wifi network.

First, find out exactly which cable modem you have.  Some Arris Cable Modems like this [SBG6580](http://www.surfboard.com/products/sbg6580/) support dual band WiFi, which means they can broadcast at 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz.  If you have one of those, try using one or the other frequency to see if your phone is having problems with one of them.

It may also help to find out what kind of wireless router or modem they're using at work.  For example, if they're both using Wireless-N and broadcasting on a 5GHz frequency, then the frequency isn't the problem.  In that case, it could be a problem with the specific modem you have - getting it replaced might help.

Comment: I changed my SSID, encryption, modes (B,G,N to G,N and to N only), 20 Mhz to 20/40Mhz. My modem is model TG862A.